# faster more optimized way of doing this?

Tags: jquery, optimization

Is there a faster more optimized way of accomplishing this?

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/search/?') >= 0) {
    if ($.cookie("Layout") == "Poster") {
        $("link").attr("href", "../css/list.css");
    } else if ($.cookie("Layout") == "Poster") {
        $("link:first").attr("href", "css/list.css");
    }
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf('/search/?') >= 0) {
    if ($.cookie("Layout") == "Description") {
        $("link").attr("href", "../css/desc.css");
    } else if ($.cookie("Layout") == "Description") {
        $("link:first").attr("href", "css/desc.css");
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with you could avoid repeating the test.

Comment: Yes, that could definitely be optimized, however you won't see any noticeable difference in execution time. It'l just be easier to maintain.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do and why, and format your code so that it is better readable.

Comment: A (not user noticeable) difference would come from caching of `$.cookie("layout')`.

Comment: The optimization here would be to optimize maintainability and make your code a bit more readable. But as mentioned already - the actual performance optimization is minimal

Comment: if performance optimizations at this level are a concern why in the world would you be using jQuery or at a minimum the jQuery.cookie plugin?

Comment: I formatted your code so I can actually read it. Are you aware that the `else if`s are never reached since you are checking the same condition as in the `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are actually testing the same thing as the original condition in an `else if` clause. This is redundant. The `else if` condition will never execute because you are in the `else` clause of the same conditional expression (confusing myself just thinking about it)..

```
if ($.cookie("Layout") == "Poster") {
  ...
}else if ($.cookie("Layout") == "Poster") { ... }
```

That should shout out to you as something wrong... The second if statement will simply never ever execute...

What you might want to do is use a `switch` statement. Something similar to this -

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/search/?') >= 0) { 
    switch($.cookie("Layout")){
       case "Layout" :
         // behavior for "Layout"
       break;
       case "Description" : 
         // behavior for "Description"
       break;
       default : 
         // behavior for unknown $.cookie("Layout") value
       break;
    }
}
```